# How can I know when the user cancels HTML5 geolocation?

Tags: html, geolocation

Sometimes I'd like to know if the user does not choose to share his location. Is there an event that gets called when the share location pop up is closed without sharing?

PS: The error callback does not get called when the user does not share his location.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This topic answers the same question:
[Geolocation feedback while accepting the request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736057/geolocation-feedback-while-accepting-the-request)

I have copied some of the code below, but check the page as there is an example of how to handle them no accepting or denying but ignoring the request on a timeout.

```
// navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successCallback, errorCallback, options);
navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(
  function(position){
    //do something with position;
  }, function(error){
    // error passed to function
    //handle condition where position is not available
    //more specifically you can check the error code...
    //error.code == 1
    if(error.PERMISSION_DENIED){
      alert("you denied me! ");
    }
});
```

Comment: That's not native code, though. The answer in the question you linked to basically writes his own version on top of getCurrentPosition. He handles it with a timeout event which is what I did as well, but I was hoping there was an event callback. oh well.

Answer (score 0):

Reading this article will provide you with a good guide on what you are asking.
http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/geolocation.html

and also

http://diveintohtml5.ep.io/detect.html#geolocation

Comment: Who says I didn't? Those articles say nothing about what I am asking.