# Issue with geolocation timeout callback firing whether response received or not

Tags: html, geolocation, timeout

I've implemented a timer for a HTML5 geolocation request as per this post [Geolocation feedback while accepting the request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4736057/geolocation-feedback-while-accepting-the-request/4748036#4748036)

However I'm having an issue where the timer is called regardless of whether the navigator.geolocation.received response is true or not. Perhaps I'm missing something very obvious but I can't see what.

Basically, if I get the geo-location information I run the `geo_success_action()` function, but in every other case (geo-location failure, timeout on accepting location share, or non-existence of html5 geo-location support in the browser), I want to run the `geo_failure_action()` function.

However what's happening is that if geo-location is collected, my `geo_success_action()` function is called, and then when the timer runs out the `geo_failure_action()` is also called.

I had assumed that within var succeed, the setting of `navigator.geolocation.received = true` would be passed to my `timedout` function and therefore if `navigator.geolocation.received` was true, it wouldn't fire the resulting function.

Any thoughts?

```
var succeed = function(obj) {
    navigator.geolocation.received = true;
    if (!navigator.geolocation.timedout) {
        geo_success_action( obj, json_url );
    }
};
var failed = function(obj) { 
    navigator.geolocation.received = true;
    if (!navigator.geolocation.timedout) {
        geo_failure_action( json_url );
    } else {
        geo_failure_action( json_url );
    }
};
var timedout = function() {
    navigator.geolocation.timedout = true; // could be used for other callbacks to trace if its timed out or not
    if (!navigator.geolocation.received){
        geo_failure_action( json_url );
        //alert('Timed Out');
    } else {
        null;
    }
}

// Extend geolocation object
if ( navigator.geolocation  ) {
    navigator.geolocation.retrievePermission = function retrievePermission(succeed,failed,options,timeout) {
        this.received = false;              // reference for timeout callback
        this.timedout = false;              // reference for other callbacks
        this.getCurrentPosition.apply(this,arguments);  // actual request

        // Trigger timeout with its function; default timeout offset 5000ms
        if ( timeout ) {
            setTimeout(timeout.callback,timeout.offset || 5000);
        }
    }

    // New location request with timeout callback
    navigator.geolocation.retrievePermission(succeed,failed,{},{
        offset: 6000, // miliseconds
        callback: timedout  
    });

// If geo-location not supported at all, do failure action
} else {
    geo_failure_action( json_url );
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't tested, but this should work

```
var timedout = function() {
    navigator.geolocation.timedout = true; 

    if( navigator.geolocation.received === undefined ) {
        navigator.geolocation.received = true;
    }

    if (!navigator.geolocation.received){
        geo_failure_action( json_url );
        //alert('Timed Out');
    } else {
        null;
    }
}
```

Comment: Sweet! That did the job nicely. I did some more digging after your answer and it turns out that it was only an issue in Firefox. For some reason in Firefox the timedout function was returning the `navigator.geolocation.received` as undefined. I hadn't spotted that. Chrome was returning it as true.