# navigator.geolocation error function firing twice

Tags: javascript

I'm requesting permission from my user to get their location from their browser using the following function:

```
if (navigator.geolocation) {
    navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(set_map_location,geoloc_error,{
        enableHighAccuracy:false,
        maximumAge:85000,
        timeout:15000
    });
}
```

And if something goes wrong, or the process times out, my `geoloc_err` function is called:

```
function geoloc_error(err) {
    if (err.code == 1) {
        alert("You denied the browser access to your location."
        + "\nYou can find your position manually by dragging the map and zooming in/out.");
    } else if (err.code == 2) {
        alert("The geolocation network is not available or your position could not be found."
        + "\nYou can find your position manually by dragging the map and zooming in/out.");
    } else {
        alert("The browser took too long to find your location. Trying again can sometimes yield different results.\n"
        + "You can find your position manually by dragging the map and zooming in/out.");
    }
}
```

Now, sometimes an error occurs, for example, `err.code==2 the network was unavailable`, and an alert pops up and warns me. The problem is, a few seconds later, another alert box warns me that the process has also timed out.

My question is, how can I stop the second error warning occurring? I can't exit the function because the error is being called from the first function.

Comment: Maybe this could help [Issue with geolocation timeout callback firing whether response received or not](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9738167/issue-with-geolocation-timeout-callback-firing-whether-response-received-or-not/9740300#9740300)